# Search for multiple word uisng postgres and javascript

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I want to search for multiple words using this query below. when i search for 'document role' I should get all documents that have all document and all document that has role in it using sequelize

```
function searchDocuments(req, res) {
  const limit = req.query.limit || 6,
    offset = req.query.offset || 0,
    queryString = req.query.q,
    splitString = queryString.split(' ');
  let querySearch = '';

  splitString.forEach((query, index, initial) => {
    console.log(initial[index]);
  });


  if (!queryString) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: 'Invalid search input'
    });
  }
  if (req.decoded.roleId === 1) {
    return Document.findAndCountAll({
     limit,
      offset,
      where: {
        title: {
          $iLike: `%${querySearch}%`
        }
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: User,
          attributes: ['userName', 'roleId']
        }
      ]
    })
    .then(({ rows: document, count }) => {
      if (count === 0) {
        return res.status(404).json({
          message: 'Search term does not match any document.'
        });
      }
      res.status(200).send({
        document,
        pagination: pagination(count, limit, offset),
      });
    })
    .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
```

I just want a sequelize query that perform does an OR task with the keyword of title

Comment: Have you took a look into postgresql's full text search feature?

Comment: yes and I have gotten a fix for it already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the top add the following code:

```
const limit = req.query.limit || 6,
    offset = req.query.offset || 0,
    queryString = req.query.q.replace(/ +(?= )/g, ''),
    searchQuery = [];

  if (!queryString) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: 'Invalid search input'
    });
  }

  if (req.decoded.roleId === 1) {
    const splitString = queryString.trim().split(' ');

    splitString.forEach((query) => {
      const output = { $iLike: `%${query}%` };
      searchQuery.push(output);
    });
```

Then add the following where you are querying `searchQuery`:

```
     where: {
        title: {
          $or: searchQuery
        }
      }
```